Measure ping for array of servers bypassing socks5 proxy in Swift
Working with xRay vpn core (LibXray). Trying to ping my proxy server list when connected to vpn. Need to check tcp ping from device to ip address bypassing vpn (like its not connected).
Made direct routing rule in xRayConfiguration to connect only for ping needs and while measuring connected to it using sockets - not accurate but i guess its not far from truth:
import Network

class TCPSocks5Ping {
    //local socks5 proxy 
    private let proxyHost: NWEndpoint.Host
    private let proxyPort: NWEndpoint.Port
    //ping destination server
    private let destinationHost: NWEndpoint.Host
    private let destinationPort: NWEndpoint.Port
    private let queue: DispatchQueue
    private let destinationHostString: String
    
    init(proxyHost: String, proxyPort: UInt16, destinationHost: String, destinationPort: UInt16, queue: DispatchQueue) {
        self.proxyHost = NWEndpoint.Host(proxyHost)
        self.proxyPort = NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: proxyPort)
        self.destinationHost = NWEndpoint.Host(destinationHost)
        self.destinationPort = NWEndpoint.Port(integerLiteral: destinationPort)
        self.destinationHostString = destinationHost
        self.queue = queue
    }

    func ping(completion: @escaping (TimeInterval?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let connection = NWConnection(host: proxyHost, port: proxyPort, using: .tcp)
        
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
            switch state {
            case .waiting(let error):
                print("Connection: Waiting - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error)
            case .ready:
                print("Connection: Ready")
                self.socks5Handshake(connection: connection, completion: completion)
            case .failed(let error):
                print("Connection: Failed - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        connection.start(queue: queue)
    }
    
    private func socks5Handshake(connection: NWConnection, completion: @escaping (TimeInterval?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let socks5InitData = Data([0x05, 0x01, 0x00])  // SOCKS5, 1 method, no authentication
        connection.send(content: socks5InitData, completion: .contentProcessed({ error in
            if let error = error {
                print("SOCKS5 Init Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 2, maximumLength: 2) { data, _, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("SOCKS5 Init Receive Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                if let data = data, data.count == 2, data[0] == 0x05, data[1] == 0x00 {
                    print("SOCKS5 Init Successful")
                    self.connectThroughSocks5(connection: connection, completion: completion)
                } else {
                    print("SOCKS5 Init Failed: Invalid response data")
                    completion(nil, NSError(domain: "SOCKS5InitFailed", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                }
            }
        }))
    }
    
    private func connectThroughSocks5(connection: NWConnection, completion: @escaping (TimeInterval?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let destinationAddress = self.destinationHostString
        guard let destinationAddressData = destinationAddress.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("Invalid Destination Host")
            completion(nil, NSError(domain: "InvalidDestinationHost", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
        var connectData = Data([0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03])  // SOCKS5, CONNECT, reserved, domain name
        connectData.append(UInt8(destinationAddressData.count))  // domain name length
        connectData.append(destinationAddressData)  // domain name
        connectData.append(UInt8(destinationPort.rawValue >> 8))  // port high byte
        connectData.append(UInt8(destinationPort.rawValue & 0xFF))  // port low byte
        
        connection.send(content: connectData, completion: .contentProcessed({ error in
            if let error = error {
                print("SOCKS5 Connect Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 10, maximumLength: 10) { data, _, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("SOCKS5 Connect Receive Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                if let data = data, data.count >= 10, data[1] == 0x00 {
                    print("SOCKS5 Connect Successful")
                    self.sendHTTPRequest(final: false, connection: connection, completion: completion)
                } else {
                    print("SOCKS5 Connect Failed: Invalid response data")
                    completion(nil, NSError(domain: "SOCKS5ConnectFailed", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                }
            }
        }))
    }
    
    private func sendHTTPRequest(final: Bool, connection: NWConnection, completion: @escaping (TimeInterval?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let httpRequest = "HEAD / HTTP /1.1\r\nHost: \(self.destinationHost)\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
        guard let pingData = httpRequest.data(using: .utf8) else {
            print("Invalid HTTP Request")
            completion(nil, NSError(domain: "InvalidHTTPRequest", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
            return
        }
        
        var startTime: DispatchTime?
        if final {
            startTime = DispatchTime.now()
        }
        
        connection.send(content: pingData, completion: .contentProcessed { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("HTTP Request Send Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 1024) { data, _, _, error in
                if final {
                    let endTime = DispatchTime.now()
                    connection.cancel()
                    if let error = error {
                        print("HTTP Request Receive Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        completion(nil, error)
                        return
                    }
                    if let _ = data {
                        guard let startTime else { return }
                        let duration = Double((endTime.uptimeNanoseconds - startTime.uptimeNanoseconds) / 1_000_000)
                        completion(duration, nil)
                    } else {
                        completion(nil, NSError(domain: "HTTPRequestFailed", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                    }
                } else {
                    self.sendHTTPRequest(final: true, connection: connection, completion: completion)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

Tried direct connection to proxyHost and proxyPort - didnt work too.
Tried to send request with just word "PING" and etc.
I wonder if someone could help because im desperate.

Declare an instance of NWParameters
let parameters = NWParameters(tls: nil, tcp: .init())

Prohibit using the ".other" types of interfaces.

The network interface type used for communication over virtual networks or networks of unknown types.

parameters.prohibitedInterfaceTypes = [.other]

Start your connection using the parameters
connection = NWConnection(to: endpoint, using: parameters)

